# Get path of CustomLineCap C#

Tags: c#, system.drawing, graphicspath

How do I get information about `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CustomLineCap`'s paths ?
I can construct CustomLineCap by giving it fillPath and strokePath:
constructor - `CustomLineCap(GraphicsPath, GraphicsPath)`.

But is there any way to extract fillPath and strokePath from it ?

Comment: +1: I had a look through documentation and it doesn't look like it

Comment: Inspected the [`System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CustomLineCap.cs` source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/CustomLineCap.cs) and there is no clue.